# Failing to resume from hibernation, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, hibernate, resume

I'm trying to hibernate Ubuntu 20.04, but it's not working. It does hibernate, apparently, but then fails to load properly when I restart. I've checked information from various pages, but mainly ended up landing on this page, which looked fairly comprehensive:

[How to set up Hibernate on Ubuntu 20.04](https://blog.ivansmirnov.name/how-to-set-up-hibernate-on-ubuntu-20-04/)

I've followed everything that he said, up to the point where he talks about writing the resume UUID to /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume (which I did). I have a swap partition, 6GB larger than the size of the actual RAM (following a suggestion that I saw on another page), so I assume that it's more than ample. Since the guy's blog suggests taking away the quiet splash, I did that, and here's the picture showing:

[Where it freezes!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8U5i.jpg)

It just hangs at that last message, without any sense that it's going to do something eventually. I've searched for information about which file/setting I need to change in order to use "no_console_suspend", but no joy there so far.

The general sense I'm getting is that it's all a bit more problematic than it should be. Why is that? I also notice that despite having installed hibernate and pm-utils, as per instructions, the hibernate option doesn't automatically appear in the menu alongside shut-down/restart/suspend/etc. Is there a good reason for that?

OK, thanks in advance, of course, for constructive feedback!

Comment: Were I in your position, I would start with https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelHibernate

Comment: "*it's all a bit more problematic than it should be*" hibernate is complex (many permutations) and some hardware is not fully compatible (hardware manufacturer's fault). Since the Ubuntu developers cannot guarantee that hibernate will work, it's not enabled.

Comment: If you have a SSD in your system a normal startup can be as fast as waking up from hybernation.

Comment: Sure, I have SSD, and that's a fair comment, but I just am really used to using hibernation with Windows, and would like to be able to do it. But fair enough - if it's complicated I'll leave it (now wondering why people put posts that don't warn users about the possible difficulties). I'll check the links from the first comment, anyway. So thanks to both commentors :~)

Comment: You must have as much contiguous swap space as you have RAM. Read `man pm-is-supported`.

Comment: Well, I said in my question that my swap partition is 6GB larger than the RAM, so presumably that's not an issue. 
`pm-is-supported --hibernate` returns nothing, as does `pm-is-supported --suspend` (and suspend works fine, of course)